# How to map 2 lists with comparison in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of objects of say foos. 
I have a loop for creating a new list.

`foo1 = {id:1,location:2}`
for e.g. `foos = [foo1,foo2,foo3]`

Now I want to create a new list based on location.

```
new_list = []
for foo in foos:
  if foo.location==2:
      new_list.append(foo)
```

What I want to know is there any way in which I can do something like this

```
new_list = []
new_list = map(if foo.location ==2,foos) // this is wrong code but is something like this possible. ?
```

Can I use map function here ? if yes how ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure thing you can do it with function. You can use the `filter` [builtin function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
new_list = filter(lambda foo: foo.location == 2, foos)
```

But the more general and "pythonic" way is to use [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
new_list = [foo for foo in foos if foo.location == 2]
```

Answer (score 6):

[List comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) seems to be what you want to use:

```
new_list = [foo for foo in foos if foo.location == 2]
```

`map` is good when you want to apply a function to **every** item in a list *(or any iterable)* and get a list of equal length *(or an iterator in Python3)* as a result. It can't "skip" items based on some condition.

Answer (score 1):

Have u tied with **filter with lambda** function
for example,

```
a = {'x': 1, 'location': 1}
b = {'y': 2, 'location': 2}
c = {'z': 3, 'location': 2}
d=[a,b,c]
```

as per ur example d will be

```
d = [{'x': 1, 'location': 1}, {'y': 2, 'location': 2}, {'z': 3, 'location': 2}]
output = filter(lambda s:s['location']==2,d)'
print output'
```

result should be,

```
[{'y': 2, 'location': 2}, {'z': 3, 'location': 2}]
```

I hope this may be u expected...